# zsh: alias with $(command) parameter

Tags: zsh

## My Goal

I'm using the following command quite frequently:

```
vim $(fzf)
```

It uses [fuzzy find](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to search a list of files, and then open the highlighted one in [vim](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=vim&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=3L0EWo2hHJH0kwXcqILIAQ).

[image]

## My Problem

I would like to alias `vim $(fzf)`, but when I add `alias v="vim $(fzf)"` to `.zshrc`, `fzf` is executed whenever I open a new shell.

## My Question

**How do I set `zsh` to execute the `$(command)` only when the aliased command is executed?**

Comment: You need to quote the command substitution as well to accommodate file names containing, e.g., whitespace.

Answer (score 8):

Simply replace

```
alias v="vim $(fzf)"
```

With

```
alias v='vim "$(fzf)"'
```